# How Do You Unescape Special Characters In A Python String?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-re

From `spam\/eggs` to `spam/eggs`

```py
# This isn't working...
str = "spam\/eggs"
s = bytes(str, "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")

print(s)
>>> spam\/eggs

# How to get "spam/eggs"
```

Comment: Check `"spam\/eggs".encode().decode()` did this respond to your question ?

Comment: `bytes("spam/eggs", "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape") == "spam/eggs"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python you can't use a '\' because python will think you will add something after it like '\t', '\n', etc. So you can use an extra backwards slash in the string: `string = 'spam\\/eggs'`

I don't think this is the most effiencient way to do this a differnt way but you can do this:

```py
strs = 'spam\/eggs'
print(strs)
strs = strs.replace('\\','')
print(strs)
```

I just deleted the `\` by replacing it with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions.

To remove especifically the special character \ you must specify to regex \ \

```py
import re
myString = "spam\/eggs"
str2 = re.sub(r'\\', "", myString) # remove this character '\'
print(str2)
# spam/eggs
```

General purpose (remove specific characters) :

```
import re
myString = "sp&a+m\/eg*gs"
str2 = re.sub(r'[\\&+*]', "", myString) # to remove what you want into the brackets
print(str2)
# spam/eggs
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is more accurate `str2 = re.sub(r'\\/', "/", myString)` for generic purposes

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "spam/eggs"
str2 = bytes(str, "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")
print(str2)
```

BTW: you should place the code in the question more carefully; you call a variable `str` then `myString` and the second variable `str2` then `str1`